# Send Facebook notifications for pages I administer to an email address other than my primary one

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, account-management, notifications

Is it possible to set up Facebook to send notifications for pages where I am the admin to an email address that isn't my primary one?

I'm in the process of setting up a Facebook page for our company and used my personal Facebook account to do so (i.e. I'm one of the page's admins). I also get email notifications about page activity.

However, I usually don't check my private email account (which is my primary address on Facebook) at work. Thus, I'd like to have notifications about the company page sent to my company email address (which I've already set up as a secondary email address in my Facebook profile).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just set up automatic forwarding for email that have some text that clearly states that it is Facebook notification for one of those pages and have "From:" usual for Facebook page notifications, just in case.